# Python logger ignores FileHandler and StreamHandler levels in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am trying to set a different logger level for my log files and stream, and I have (seemingly) followed the demo (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) to the dot. However, in my actual code it does not work. Running this demo bare in a test script works:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')

print(logger.handlers)
print(logger)
```

results in

```
alex@alexpc:~/Projects/claritydb$ python test.py ; cat spam.log
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (ERROR)>, <FileHandler /home/Projects/claritydb/spam.log (DEBUG)>]
<Logger simple_example (DEBUG)>
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - DEBUG - debug message
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - INFO - info message
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - WARNING - warn message
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - ERROR - error message
2019-09-16 11:53:44,293 - simple_example - CRITICAL - critical message
```

But this for some reason will not execute properly in the actual code:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self,
                 verbosity_stream="WARNING", 
                 verbosity_log="INFO"):

        self.logger = self.setup_logger(verbosity_stream=verbosity_stream, verbosity_log=verbosity_log)

    def setup_logger(self, verbosity_stream="ERROR", verbosity_log="WARNING"):

        # Create a custom logger

        logger = logging.getLogger(f"do_stuff")
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        fh = logging.FileHandler(f"do_stuff.log", mode='w')
        fh.setLevel(getattr(logging, verbosity_log))

        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(getattr(logging, verbosity_stream))

        # create formatter and add it to the handlers
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add the handlers to the self.logger
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.addHandler(fh)

        print(logger.handlers)

        return logger
```

Any invocations to self.logger output both to the console and the logfile at the logging.DEBUG level -- which is obviously not what I want. I am very confused as to what I am missing since when I ask the main method what its filehandlers are I get

```
print(self.logger.handlers)
print(self.logger)
```

```
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (ERROR)>, <FileHandler /home/Projects/claritydb/do_stuff.log (DEBUG)>]
<Logger do_stuff (DEBUG)>
```

Which is identical to the test case, but there are all the info level outputs in both my console and log file. Changing my handler.setLevel commands has no effect on the output, the only thing that changes it is the change of the setLevel command to the initial logger call at the very top of the definitions (i.e. ch.setLevel and fh.setLevel have no effect, but logger.setLevel does [And I think it is only supposed to be the initial filter).

This is driving me nuts, does anyone have any idea?

EDIT1: Changing the

```
logger = logging.getLogger(f"do_stuff")
```

line to

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

seems to solve the problem, but I have no idea why...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in question. `MyClass(verbosity_stream="ERROR", verbosity_log="DEBUG").logger.info('...')` prints to file, but not to terminal. The error lies somewhere else - most probably you are configuring logging somewhere else. Look for `logging.basicConfig` in your code or `logging` usages in general.

Comment: I am sure I am not using basicConfig -- I never set up the logger with this in the first place. I think somehow I have to disable the root logger's output

Comment: Maybe you are importing some third party library. They can add handlers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `logger = logging.getLogger()` you are getting the root logger and afterwards append your handlers and set its level and so on. When you do `logger = logging.getLogger(f"do_stuff")` you are getting a logger called `do_stuff` but the root logger still exists and your newly created logger propagates it's logs to the root loggers handlers. Since in that scenario the root logger has no handlers added to it, it uses the default `logging.lastResort` with it's default level. You can fix this in a number of ways. One easy solution is to set `logger.propagate = False`.

You also don't need this `fh.setLevel(getattr(logging, verbosity_log))`. Python handles the strings passed in directly just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I tried
`logger = logging.getLogger(f"do_stuff")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.propogate = False`

But I still ran into the same problem -- it is printing debug level output to the console despite the stream handler being set to warning and the log handler being set to info.

And thanks for the tip about the strings! saves an extra complication

Comment: Are you sure you have no typo in there? says `logger.propogate` in your snippet here, but you need to set `propagate` (with an a)

Comment: Nope it was definitely a typo -- now it works. It didn't throw any kind of fuss at the typo! That's annoying. Dumb mistake but problem solved! Thanks

Comment: @Alex if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.